# How can I scrape tables that seem to be hidden by jquery?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape these words with their meanings on this [website](https://www.graduateshotline.com/gre-word-list.html), I scraped the first table, but even after revealing word list 2 by clicking on it, `bs4` can't find that table (or any other of the hidden tables). Is there anything different I'm meant to do for toggled/hidden elements like this?

Here's what I used to access the first table:

```
root = "https://www.graduateshotline.com/gre-word-list.html#x2"

content = requests.get(root).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table',attrs={'class':'tablex border1'})[0]
print(table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://www.graduateshotline.com/gre/load.php?file=list2.html',
                  attrs={'class': 'tablex border1'})[0]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    0                                                  1
0        multifarious                varied; motley; greatly diversified
1      substantiation                giving facts to support (statement)
2                feud          bitter quarrel over a long period of time
3    indefatigability               not easily exhaustible; tirelessness
4          convoluted                        complicated;coiled; twisted
..                ...                                                ...
257        insensible              unconscious; unresponsive; unaffected
258          gourmand  a person who is devoted to eating and drinking...
259             plead              address a court of law as an advocate
260            morbid            diseased; unhealthy (e.g.. about ideas)
261            enmity                              hatred being an enemy

[262 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you could access it like that.